# Branching Combine operator, flatMap, and debounce oddity

Tags: swift, combine

### Context

I am following the example from WWDC 2019 722 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/722/ and WWDC 2019 721 https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/ and making a field with validation the runs an asynchronous network check on a field.

What should happen, as mentioned in the talk, is that the username field should:

1. Debounce
2. Show a loading indicator
3. Perform the network request
4. End with the network result
5. Hide the loading indicator
6. And show or hide a validation message as a result of the network response

I have a prototype that has the debounce, and mocks the network request by using the delay operator. All of this is working well for the most part.

```swift
let a = $firstName
    .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
    .flatMap { name -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> in
        if name == "" {
            return Just(name)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return Just(name)
                .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in self.isFirstNameLoading = true})
                .delay(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in self.isFirstNameLoading = false})
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
    .map { name -> Bool in name != "Q" }
    .assign(to: \.isFirstNameValid, on: self)
```

The debounce waits until the input has paused. The `flatMap` acts as a conditional branching in the Combine flow of operators: if the value is empty, do not bother with the network request; else, if the value has value after the debounce, perform the network request. Lastly, my example is that "Q" is always an error, for mock purposes.

However, the slight problem is that the debounce happens before the branching. I would like to move the debounce to the else branch of the conditional, like so.

```swift
let a = $firstName
    .flatMap { name -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> in
        if name == "" {
            return Just(name)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return Just(name)
                .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in self.isFirstNameLoading = true})
                .delay(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in self.isFirstNameLoading = false})
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
    .map { name -> Bool in name != "Q" }
    .assign(to: \.isFirstNameValid, on: self)
```

When this happens, the true branch of the conditional (empty input) is run correctly, and the map+assign after the flatMap run correctly. However, when the input has value, and the else branch of the conditional runs, nothing after the debounce is run at all.

I have tried switching the `DispatchQueue` to `OperationQueue.main` and `RunLoop.main` to no avail.

Keeping the debounce to before the conditional works okay for now, but I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong with my attempt to put it in the branch. I'm also wondering if this would be the correct way to do "branching" in operators with Combine, particularly with my use of `flatMap` and `Just()`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A `Just` only ever produces one output. Attaching a `debounce` to it is not going to debounce anything. At best, it will just delay the output of the `Just` by the debounce interval. At worst, there's a bug preventing it from working at all, which is what it sounds like based on your description.

Comment: I wonder if it is because the `Just` publisher "finishes" before the end of the debounce period. From the docs about `Just`: "A publisher that emits an output to each subscriber just once, and then finishes."

Comment: I chose to use throttle in my examples, but almost exactly what you're after is in the sample code for Using Combine - refs: https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-update-interface-userinput and https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-cascading-update-interface

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a bit late to answer here, but I figure this will be good for the next guy.

The goal is to: *debounce only if the `name` is non-empty*. Unfortunately, that's not possible:

- every time the `firstName` field changes, a value is sent down the stream
- every time `flatMap` receives a value, it creates *a new stream*

Debouncing means "do this if you're not told to do something else within a time limit." The `Just` publisher can't be debounced (meaningfully) because it will never "tell to do something else." It sends one output, and ends. Each change to `firstName` creates a new `Just` publisher, and a new debouncer for the new publisher. It doesn't debounce across different publishers.

That being said, you could achieve the kind of behavior you described as follows (some convenient syntax is only available in later Swift versions, but you get the idea). Let's redefine the problem:

- IF the string is empty, I want some behavior
- ELSE I want some other behavior

Your answer was halfway there... we *do* want different streams, but we *don't* need them to be mushed into a single stream:

```swift
class MyThing {
    @Published var firstName: String = ""
    @Published var isFirstNameValid = false
    @Published var isFirstNameLoading = false

    func subscribeToFirstName() {
        // no debouncing for empty values
        $firstName
            .filter { $0 == "" } // 1
            .map { _ in true }   // 2
            .assign(to: &$isFirstNameValid)

        // debounce non-empty values
        $firstName
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main) // 3
            .filter { $0 != "" } // 4
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [weak self] _ in self?.isFirstNameLoading = true }) // beware strong reference cycles in Combine!
            .delay(for: .seconds(2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { [weak self] _ in self?.isFirstNameLoading = false })
            .map { name -> Bool in name != "Q" }
            .assign(to: &$isFirstNameValid)
    }
}
```

1. create a stream that *only* listens to empty strings
2. we know that empty strings are always != "Q", so we can use a constant to say that it is valid as a firstName
3. we create a completely separate stream (only one, not per output) and debounce values coming in
4. we only continue if the last value that made it through is non-empty (it's important to put this after the `debounce`, not before it. Try playing with it in a Playground to figure out why! :) )

In short: we want data to go through two different processes. We want *different data* to go through different processes. So we make different streams. Your solution was halfway there, it just requires thinking about Combine different from what we're used to.

PS: Keep an eye out for strong reference cycles! It's far too easy to accidentally capture an implicit strong-self, which is held as part of our stream. Remember, the subscription at the bottom (`assign(to:)`) holds the sum of everything above it. Strong references matter through the entire stream, not just the beginning and end. If an operator in the middle captures a strong self, and self holds the subscription... which holds the strong self... you're gonna have a bad time :P